# Facebook API, export group wall entries

Tags: c#, php, facebook, api

After trying to find a reference to an API/tutorial to such thing, I have come here.

I would like to scan a specific group wall, pulling all posts from it, with PHP or C#.

In the end, I would like to have a nested-array containing each posts, with the next details:

- An array of the related comments
- Likes
- Views

Obviously, I don't ask for any code, only a reference to the related API I will need to use.

**EDIT:** If this is not possible, should I consider cURL as an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/GROUP_ID/feed` endpoint contains all this data.

Example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=195466193802264%2Ffeed

Note: The "viewed by" feature is not available through an API.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Am I able to request all the entries, and not 25 of them each time?